# why is array undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, undefined

when executing the following code firebug tells me: *values[this.geo.value] is undefined*
what is the problem?

```
$.get('./RDFexamples/tin00089_test2.rdf', null, function (rdfXml) {
var rdf, json = {};
var values = new Array();

rdf = $.rdf()
    .load(rdfXml)
    .prefix('', 'http://ontologycentral.com/2009/01/eurostat/ns#')
    .prefix('qb', 'http://purl.org/linked-data/cube#')
    .prefix('rdf', 'http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#')
    .prefix('dcterms', 'http://purl.org/dc/terms/')
    .prefix('sdmx-measure', 'http://purl.org/linked-data/sdmx/2009/measure#')
    .where('?observation a qb:Observation')
    .where('?observation dcterms:date ?date')
    .where('?observation sdmx-measure:obsValue ?measure')
    .where('?observation :geo ?geo')
    .each(function () {
        values[this.geo.value].push(this.measure.value);
        //alert(this.date.value)
        //alert(this.measure.value)
        //alert(this.geo.value)
    }
    );
    alert(values);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

values[this.geo.value] is never initialized so you can't do .push because values[this.geo.value] is undefined, you first need to create an array in values[this.geo.value] before you can push things into it.

**Pseudo-code example**

```
if values[this.geo.value] == undefined {
    values[this.geo.value] = []
}
values[this.geo.value].push(...)
```

Answer (score 2):

`push` is a method of the Array object itself - you are calling it on a value within the Array (which has probably not been set, hence 'undefined'). It's unclear what `this.geo.value` is, but assuming its the index of the array item you are trying to set, your options are:

```
values.push(this.measure.value);
```

or

```
values[this.geo.value] = this.measure.value;
```